# Python - Converted Nested JSON with Nested Columns

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe, nested, multiple-columns

I am new to Python and JSON data structures and was looking for some assistance

I have been able to create some Python code that calls a Web API and converts the returning JSON data (report_rows) into a dataframe successfully using json_normalize()

I am having some issues converting and sorting the JSON column names into the dataframe column names and was wondering if I could get some help on the following...

1. *Get Column Names from JSON data* - In the dataframe I would like to convert the column names: c1, c2, c3, etc to RECORD_NO, REF_RECORD_NO, SOV_LINEITEM_NO.  The column names are in the JSON data [data][report_header][cXX][name] where cXX is the column number
2. *Sort Column Names* - I would like to order the dataframe columns so instead of c1, c10, c11, c12, c2, c3, etc it is c1, c2, c3 ... c10, c11,c12

If someone is able to provide some help, it would be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

**Python Code**

```
json_data = json.loads(res.read())
data = pd.json_normalize(json_data['data'], record_path=['report_row'])
print(data)
```

which outputs the following

```
            c1 c10            c11  ...               c7            c8        c9
0  CON-0000001  71    VEN-0000001  ...  Build IT System  Contract 123   Pending
1  CON-0000002  72    VEN-0000002  ...  Build IT System  Contract XYZ  Approved
```

**JSON Data**

```
  "data": [
    {
      "report_header": {
        "c11": {
          "name": "VENDOR_RECORD",
          "type": "java.lang.String"
        },
        "c10": {
          "name": "VENDOR_ID",
          "type": "java.lang.Integer"
        },
        "c12": {
          "name": "VENDOR_NAME",
          "type": "java.lang.String"
        },
        "c1": {
          "name": "RECORD_NO",
          "type": "java.lang.String"
        },
        "c2": {
          "name": "REF_RECORD_NO",
          "type": "java.lang.String"
        },
        "c3": {
          "name": "SOV_LINEITEM_NO",
          "type": "java.lang.String"
        },
        "c4": {
          "name": "REF_ITEM",
          "type": "java.lang.String"
        },
        "c5": {
          "name": "PROJECTNUMBER",
          "type": "java.lang.String"
        },
        "c6": {
          "name": "PROJECTNAME",
          "type": "java.lang.String"
        },
        "c7": {
          "name": "TITLE",
          "type": "java.lang.String"
        },
        "c8": {
          "name": "CONTRACT_NO",
          "type": "java.lang.String"
        },
        "c9": {
          "name": "STATUS",
          "type": "java.lang.String"
        }
      },
      "report_row": [
        {
          "c1": "CON-0000001",
          "c10": "71  ",
          "c11": "VEN-0000001",
          "c12": "Microsoft",
          "c2": "",
          "c3": "1",
          "c4": "",
          "c5": "P-0037",
          "c6": "Project ABC",
          "c7": "Build IT System",
          "c8": "Contract 123",
          "c9": "Pending"
        },
        {
          "c1": "CON-0000002",
          "c10": "72  ",
          "c11": "VEN-0000002",
          "c12": "Google",
          "c2": "",
          "c3": "1.1",
          "c4": "",
          "c5": "P-0037",
          "c6": "Project ABC",
          "c7": "Build IT System",
          "c8": "Contract XYZ",
          "c9": "Approved"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "message": [
    "OK"
  ],
  "status": 200
}
```

Comment: i was able to resolve my question by doing the following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to resolve the issue by adding the following code...

```
# Get the number of fields/columns in the JSON data
number_of_fields = len((json_data['data'][0]['report_header']))
reorder_columns = []
new_column_names = []
field_index = 0

# Loop through the Columns and do the following...
# reorder_columns - this is the column order that i want: c1, c2, c3 ... c10, c11, c12
# new_column_name - this will retrieve the column names from the header: c1.name, c2.name, etc
while field_index < number_of_fields:
    field_index += 1
    new_column = "c" + str(field_index)
    reorder_columns.append(new_column) 
    column_header = new_column + '.name'
    new_column_name = header.iloc[0][new_column + '.name']
    new_column_names.append(new_column_name)

data = pd.json_normalize(json_data['data'], record_path=['report_row'])
data = data.reindex(columns=reorder_columns)
data.columns = new_column_names
```